# Find all the checkboxes inside html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am generating a dynamic form. Upon adding checkboxes the following HTML is generated:

```html
<div class='selected_checkboxes'>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="931022941" class="checkboxes_line">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Checkbox Name: </label><input type="text" data-id="931022941" class="form-control checkbox_label" name="checkbox_name"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>CheckBox Value</label> <input type="text" data-id="931022941" class="form-control checkbox_value " name="checkbox_value">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="remove_checkbox btn btn-danger" value="Remove" data-id="931022941">Remove</a> <input type="checkbox" style="visibility: hidden" data-name="" data-glabel="" data-label="343" data-value="343" name="34[]" data-id="931022941" class="checkbox_item"
        value="343"> <label class="ceheckbox_text" data-id="931022941"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div calss="col-md-1">
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="867429714" class="checkboxes_line">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Checkbox Name: </label><input type="text" data-id="867429714" class="form-control checkbox_label" name="checkbox_name"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>CheckBox Value</label> <input type="text" data-id="867429714" class="form-control checkbox_value " name="checkbox_value">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="remove_checkbox btn btn-danger" value="Remove" data-id="867429714">Remove</a> <input type="checkbox" style="visibility: hidden" data-name="" data-glabel="" data-label="343" data-value="3434" name="34[]" data-id="867429714" class="checkbox_item"
        value="3434"> <label class="ceheckbox_text" data-id="867429714"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div calss="col-md-1">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to get all the checkboxes inside the HTML and use their `data` attribute, I have tried to use this:

```
var checkboxes = $('.selected_checkboxes :checkbox');
```

Then I loop on the checkboxes, but that did not work.

Can someone please advise to help me sort it out

Comment: What didn't work? Any error in console?

Comment: The line of jQuery you've shown is correct and absolutely will retrieve all checkboxes within the `.selected_checkboes` element that are not disabled. If it's not working for you then we need to see a more complete example of your JS. It's possible, for example, that you're invoking that line of code too early, before the elements exist in the DOM.

Comment: it returns me the object but i am not sure how to loop on that and get the data attriutes on that

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each & https://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: i did try each and to for loop as well to the length of the object , it did not return the values  and did not even print inside loop , not suhre why $(checkboxes).each(function( index ) {
       console.log("inside loop");
       console.log($(this).data('label'));
      });

Comment: That works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/12Le8bcj/. As I said in the previous comment, you'll need to ensure the code runs *after* you've added the elements to the DOM.

Comment: Make sure you are fetching the `checkboxes` after they are loaded in the `DOM` for example on button(`Submit`) click of the `Form`

Comment: Ensure you *do* have *jquery* included and not something else that defines `$`.  A complete snippet (edit, click `[<>]`) will help us see what you **have tried** ("*I did try each and for* - but how did you try them).  The snippet needs to demonstrate the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: these checkboxes are added dynamically( on click) so could it be the reason ? if so what could be work around  i used $('body')on('click','.add-chckbox',..   to add the checkboxes something similar required ?

Comment: Adding them dynamically doesn't matter as you're not adding events to them, just reading what's there.  So it depends on where you call `var checkboxes = $('.selected_checkboxes :checkbox');` - if it's inside the event of something that gets replaced, then no, it won't work and will need event delegation.   But you've not provided any context to your call.  Please update the question to include enough information to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without (POJS) or with JQuery:

```js
// POJS
document.querySelectorAll(".selected_checkboxes .checkbox_item")
  .forEach( cb => console.log(`data-id: ${cb.dataset.id}`) );
  
// JQuery
$(".selected_checkboxes :checkbox")
  .each( (i, cb) => console.log(`data-id: ${cb.dataset.id}`) )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='selected_checkboxes'>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div id="931022941" class="checkboxes_line">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <label>Checkbox Name: </label><input type="text" data-id="931022941" class="form-control checkbox_label" name="checkbox_name"><br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <label>CheckBox Value</label> <input type="text" data-id="931022941" class="form-control checkbox_value " name="checkbox_value">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <a class="remove_checkbox btn btn-danger" value="Remove" data-id="931022941">Remove</a>                     <input type="checkbox" style="visibility: hidden" data-name="" data-glabel="" data-label="343" data-value="343" name="34[]" data-id="931022941" class="checkbox_item" value="343"> <label class="ceheckbox_text" data-id="931022941"></label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div calss="col-md-1">
      <br>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div id="867429714" class="checkboxes_line">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <label>Checkbox Name: </label><input type="text" data-id="867429714" class="form-control checkbox_label" name="checkbox_name"><br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <label>CheckBox Value</label> <input type="text" data-id="867429714" class="form-control checkbox_value " name="checkbox_value">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <a class="remove_checkbox btn btn-danger" value="Remove" data-id="867429714">Remove</a>                     <input type="checkbox" style="visibility: hidden" data-name="" data-glabel="" data-label="343" data-value="3434" name="34[]" data-id="867429714" class="checkbox_item" value="3434"> <label class="ceheckbox_text" data-id="867429714"></label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div calss="col-md-1">
      <br>
   </div>
</div>
```